# Is the species name "Ewoks" simply "Wookiees" with the syllables reversed?

Tags: star-wars, george-lucas, ewoks

One group of the furry critters is tall and technologically advanced, while the other is smaller and more primitive. Did George Lucas state whether or not the *Ewoks* name is simply and conveniently *Wookiees* with the syllables reversed?

Comment: But Wookie backwards would be Eikoow - even dropping letters to get Ekow, they're in the wrong order...

Comment: @Izkata Backwards sounded better than sideways... ;P

Comment: @MajorStackings: "Wookie" with the syllables reversed would be "kiewoo", I think?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Oops!  I think you are right.  The k-sound probably does belong to the second syllable in "Wookiee".  Aargh!  Unfortunately, (approximate) phonetic anagram does not communicate how similar the two words are.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to http://www.nytimes.com/1997/01/26/movies/the-names-came-from-earth.html?pagewanted=2&src=pm the name Ewok was actually taken from:

> Miwok, the Indian tribe indigenous to San Rafael, Calif., the location of Mr. Lucas's Skywalker Ranch

Having said that, it sure *is* one mighty coincidence that it's "Wookiee" phoneticaly backwards, and the fact that in the [original concept](http://imaginarycinema.com/jedi.html) they *were* actually Wookiees, not Ewoks, may have some bearing on the matter:

> The Ewok battle was a rethinking of Lucas's original idea to end his first story treatment with a battle on the Wookiee planet.

Comment: Did you mean (almost--wook vs. wok) reversed syllables?  It seems that "Wookiee" phonetically backwards would be "Ekoow".

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Edited. Thanks. That's what I was trying to ask.